# Book about terraforming Venus and crossing it on foot

Tags: story-identification, books

In the early to mid eighties I read a short story or possibly a novel set on a Venus that was being terraformed. Based on what I was reading at the time I suspect it was published in the late sixties or early seventies but I can't be sure.  Think Heinlein, Asimov etc.

All I really remember was that there was constant rain and the main character was traveling (on foot I believe) then he stopped at one of a series of domed hostel type things to refresh and escape the rain.

This might be from a different story but I think the only habitable parts of the planet were very large, deep canyons. The actual surface wasn't habitable.

Comment: voted to reopen so that it can be closed as a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193578/short-story-about-interminable-rain-on-venus

Comment: @Otis FYI, mods and gold-tag-badgers have a tool for switching dupe targets without needing to reopen and reclose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Travelling by foot through endless rain on Venus is the central theme of Ray Bradburys short story ["*The Long Rain*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Rain). The sun domes provide the only relief from the all-consuming and maddening humidity and greyness.

Deep canyons as the only habitable parts of the planet are not part of the story. One story where this is a plot element is ["*Out of the Silent Planet*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_Silent_Planet) by C. S. Lewis, which is set on Mars. It is the first book of his Space Trilogy.